# Cant download azure artifacts through service principal

Tags: azure, artifacts, azure-service-principal

I am trying to fetch Azure Artifacts through Service Principal in PowerShell but not able to do it.
Reproduction step:

**az login --service-principal --username "" -p="" --tenant ""**
Above command works fine and returns the following output:
[
{
"cloudName": "",
"homeTenantId": "",
"id": "",
"isDefault": true,
"managedByTenants": [],
"name": "Microsoft Azure Enterprise",
"state": "Enabled",
"tenantId": "",
"user": {
"name": "",
"type": "servicePrincipal"
}
}
]
Then I ran the following command to download the artifacts:

az artifacts universal download --organization "" --project "" --scope project --feed "" --name "" --version "" --path .

Error:
python.exe : WARNING: Could not retrieve credential from local cache for service principal  under tenant
. Trying credential under tenant , assuming that is an app credential.
At C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.ps1:2 char:1

- & "$PSScriptRoot..\python.exe" -IBm azure.cli $args
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WARNING: Could ...app credential.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
  ```

WARNING: Could not retrieve credential from local cache for service principal    under tenant
. Trying credential under tenant , assuming that is an app credential.
ERROR: Failed to update Universal Packages tooling.
Before you can run Azure DevOps commands, you need to run the login command(az login if using AAD/MSA identity else az devops login if using PAT token)
to setup credentials.  Please see https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth for more information.

I am able to download the artifacts when I simply run **az login**, then pass the authentication through browser and then run the **az artifact download command**. But I want to automate this process through code so I need to login programmatically.

Please let me know what can I do? I have already spent a lot of days for this issue.
Thanks